# How to(Libvirt) attach floppy image device to guest VM?

Tags: virtual-machine, linux-kvm, qemu, floppy, libvirt

Say, I have floppy.vfd image.

How should I fill my xml file in order to attach floppy image?
I have template like

```
<disk type='*' device='*'>
    <device name='*' type='*'/>
    <target dev='*' bus='*'/>
</disk>
```

Yes, I searched the net for info about attaching floppies, not found, even on libvirt.org

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `device=floppy`, `dev=fda` and `bus=fdc`, e.g.

```xml
<disk type='file' device='floppy'>
  <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/floppy.vfd'/>
  <target dev='fda' bus='fdc'/>
</disk>
```

Comment: There's also another example in the [documentation](https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#hard-drives-floppy-disks-cdroms).